# React: why is getDefaultProps a method while propTypes is a plain object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since `getDefaultProps` doesn't refer to a component instance, it would seem like you wouldn't need a function (as there's no need to rebind `this`, for instance) and a plain old object would work fine. What's the advantage of using a function there, any why doesn't the same apply to `propTypes`?

Comment: Please consider  using `static defaultProps =  {

    }` syntax as per ECMA2016 in place of calling `getDefaultProps` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**propTypes**
`propTypes` is an object because it's used to declare that a prop is a specific JS primitive. For example:

```
React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    optionalArray:  React.PropTypes.array,
    optionalBool:   React.PropTypes.bool,
    optionalFunc:   React.PropTypes.func
  }
});
```

This helps to ensure components are used correctly. When an invalid value is provided for a prop a warning will be shown in the JavaScript console.

**getDefaultProps()**
`getDefaultProps` is used to define default values for `props`, and is invoked once and cached when the class is created.

**Why**
I believe the advantage, or reason rather, `getDefaultProps()` is a function is so it can be cached to avoid recalculation the next time the component is used.

Comment: Ah, function caching makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: getDefaultProps behave like a static Singleton method which returns a sharable object each time its called. Static since it get called before component instance is created and singleton so that it return a sharable object.